# Does sodium ethoxide (sodium ethanolate) have a boiling point, or does it decompose?

Tags: boiling-point

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_ethoxide), $\ce{C2H5ONa}$ melts at 260°C, but no boiling point is given. What will happen if $\ce{C2H5ONa}$ is heated further?

Comment: I don't know but my instinct is that it decomposes perhaps with loss of ethene

Comment: Yeah, it decomposes.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a reference, and do you know at what temperature it decomposes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, sodium ethoxide starts to decompose on heating and thus its boiling point cannot be determined. According to [1]:

> The decomposition of sodium ethoxide is observed to **start above 573
>   K** agreeing well with that reported by Blanchard et al. The gaseous
>   products formed on decomposition were mainly methane and ethylene with
>   minor quantities of ethane, propylene and butylene. Solid residue was
>   found to be a mixture of sodium carbonate, sodium hydroxide and
>   amorphous carbon. However, in an earlier study on decomposition of
>   sodium ethoxide, by collecting and condensing the evolved gases in
>   liquid nitrogen and analysis by gas chromatography, the authors have
>   reported the gaseous products to be mainly of ethylene and minor
>   quantities of propane, heptane, ethanol and water. The authors have
>   also stated that the non-condensable gas at liquid nitrogen
>   temperature could be hydrogen or methane. The TG trace for
>   decomposition of sodium ethoxide in their study **indicated a slow and
>   steady decomposition right from 273 K with a sharp weight change above
>   573 K** which implied that the sodium ethoxide could contain some
>   amount of ethanol and moisture that evaporated on heating.[...]

#### Reference:

1. Chandran, K.; Kamruddin, M.; Ajikumar, P.; Gopalan, A.; Ganesan, V. Kinetics of thermal decomposition of sodium methoxide and ethoxide. *J. Nucl. Mater.* **2006,** *358* (2-3), 111–128. [DOI: 10.1016/j.jnucmat.2006.07.003](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jnucmat.2006.07.003).